# Trouble with Z-Index on an absolutely positioned element

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I'm trying to get an absolutely positioned element to appear behind another element. I've set the z-indices but it doesn't seem to have any effect. The element that I am trying to place in the background is instead at the forefront.

Both elements in question are inside a container with a position set to relative. It was my understanding that this would create a fresh set of stacking elements although I'm not sure if that is even really important.

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer augue</p>
        <p>massa, scelerisque non viverra sagittis, egestas nec erat. Aliquam vel</p>
      </div>
      <div id="bg">&nbsp</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
      #wrapper {
        background: #fdd;
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #content{
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 100;
      }

      #bg{
        background: #ddf;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;        
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 40%;
        z-index:1;
      }
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/GsG28/

This is occurring in both Chrome and IE, although I haven't tested other browsers. What I am getting is this:

[image]

What I want is for the text to be on top of the blue background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#content` needs a `position: relative;` for the `z-index` to apply to it.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer when I can (need a few minutes still).

Answer (score 1):

Your `#content` area is missing its positioning:

```
      #content{
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 100;
        position:relative;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like Kolink just beat you to it.